Show/Hide specific text in MS Word
I am looking for a way to mark parts of a word document (these may be single words, sentences, or multiple paragraphs) as relevant to a certain tag or topic, and then quickly filter the document depending on what topics the document should be relevant to.
This is because our current quotes have terms and conditions which are very detailed and tedious to edit in word - some change for e.g. summer vs winter, whether certain products are included, or other simple variables. I am aiming to reduce the creation of these quotes to minimal input.
The solution must be in microsoft word as the people using the end result are unable or unwilling to learn a new program - otherwise I'd have put them on a proper CCMS by now.
Any and all recommendations much appreciated.

If the parts are disparate, that is, none of the discretionary parts is shared by multiple conditions, you could use character styles to mark the parts that you want to be shown in one condition. Format them all to be hidden text.
When you want Winter text to display, modify the Winter character style to not be hidden.
Here are references that may help with AutoText:

AutoText my writing
Where Can Building Blocks Be Stored my writing
Quick Parts vs. AutoText by Debora Savadra

You could automate the process using macros.

Absolutely brilliant suggestion, thank you. Definitely going to try this.

You are welcome.

I don't think there's any way within Word to show/hide sections of content in the way you're describing.
But, possibly the next best thing would be to look at Quick Parts and AutoText within Word.
Those allow you to take blocks of Word content and save them to the Quick Parts gallery for use later on (they get saved in the Normal template by default). Those can then be appropriately named, filed into relevant groups etc for use later. For instance you might have a quick part that is the summer version of the text for a particular product. The user then simply selects that from the Insert > Quick Parts menu and inserts the entire block of content in place.
If everyone has access to a centrally stored template file with those Quick Parks entries saved to it, they'll then all have access to the same building blocks to quickly create a new document.
